# How to get stock quote from Yahoo! Finance API into macOS Shortcuts

Tags: macos, shortcuts-app, yahoo

I am trying to create a macOS shortcut (with the Shortcuts app) that fetches some stock quotes.

According to [this web page](https://medium.com/@richardmoult75/how-to-use-an-api-with-apple-shortcuts-ce116e37fcfd), here is how to use the JSON structure:

1. Open the Shortcuts app
2. Click on the `+` sign to create a new shortcut
3. Add action `Get contents of URL`
4. Insert desired URL
5. Add action `Get dictionary from input` (which automatically gets the dictionary from the URL)
6. Add action `Get dictionary value`
7. In field `key` insert `fact`
8. Add `Show result` which will automatically set the variable name to `Dictionary Value`
9. Add action `Show result`
10. Then click on the play button
11. Authorise access
12. A pop-up message appears.

I looked up how Yahoo! Finance the API looks like thanks to [this other web page](https://syncwith.com/yahoo-finance/yahoo-finance-api) which reveals the following API structure:

```
{
  "quoteSummary": {
    "result": [
      {
        "financialData": {
          "maxAge": 86400,
          "currentPrice": {
            "raw": 144.49,
            "fmt": "144.49"
          },
          "targetHighPrice": {
            "raw": 214,
            "fmt": "214.00"
          },
          "targetLowPrice": {
            "raw": 122,
            "fmt": "122.00"
          },
          "targetMeanPrice": {
            "raw": 176.69,
            "fmt": "176.69"
          },
          "targetMedianPrice": {
            "raw": 176,
            "fmt": "176.00"
          },
          "recommendationMean": {
            "raw": 1.9,
            "fmt": "1.90"
          },
          "recommendationKey": "buy",
          "numberOfAnalystOpinions": {
            "raw": 41,
            "fmt": "41",
            "longFmt": "41"
          },
          "totalCash": {
            "raw": 48304001024,
            "fmt": "48.3B",
            "longFmt": "48,304,001,024"
          },
          "totalCashPerShare": {
            "raw": 3.036,
            "fmt": "3.04"
          },
          "ebitda": {
            "raw": 130541002752,
            "fmt": "130.54B",
            "longFmt": "130,541,002,752"
          },
          "totalDebt": {
            "raw": 132480000000,
            "fmt": "132.48B",
            "longFmt": "132,480,000,000"
          },
          "quickRatio": {
            "raw": 0.709,
            "fmt": "0.71"
          },
          "currentRatio": {
            "raw": 0.879,
            "fmt": "0.88"
          },
          "totalRevenue": {
            "raw": 394328014848,
            "fmt": "394.33B",
            "longFmt": "394,328,014,848"
          },
          "debtToEquity": {
            "raw": 261.446,
            "fmt": "261.45"
          },
          "revenuePerShare": {
            "raw": 24.317,
            "fmt": "24.32"
          },
          "returnOnAssets": {
            "raw": 0.21214001,
            "fmt": "21.21%"
          },
          "returnOnEquity": {
            "raw": 1.75459,
            "fmt": "175.46%"
          },
          "grossProfits": {
            "raw": 170782000000,
            "fmt": "170.78B",
            "longFmt": "170,782,000,000"
          },
          "freeCashflow": {
            "raw": 90215251968,
            "fmt": "90.22B",
            "longFmt": "90,215,251,968"
          },
          "operatingCashflow": {
            "raw": 122151002112,
            "fmt": "122.15B",
            "longFmt": "122,151,002,112"
          },
          "earningsGrowth": {
            "raw": 0.048,
            "fmt": "4.80%"
          },
          "revenueGrowth": {
            "raw": 0.081,
            "fmt": "8.10%"
          },
          "grossMargins": {
            "raw": 0.43310001,
            "fmt": "43.31%"
          },
          "ebitdaMargins": {
            "raw": 0.33105,
            "fmt": "33.11%"
          },
          "operatingMargins": {
            "raw": 0.30289,
            "fmt": "30.29%"
          },
          "profitMargins": {
            "raw": 0.2531,
            "fmt": "25.31%"
          },
          "financialCurrency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ],
    "error": null
  }
}
```

And here are the steps I made to get today's AAPL stock valuation:

1. Open the Shortcuts app
2. Click on the `+` sign to create a new shortcut
3. Add action `Get contents of URL`
4. Insert URL `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL`
5. Add action `Get dictionary from input` (which automatically gets the dictionary from the URL)
6. Add action `Get dictionary value`
7. In field `key` insert `financialData`
8. Add action `Set variable`
9. Set field `Variable Name` to `financialDataVar`
10. Add action `Get dictionary value`
11. In field `key` insert `currentPrice`
12. Add action `Set variable`
13. Set field `Variable Name` to `currentPriceVar`
14. Add action `Get dictionary value`
15. In field `key` insert `raw`
16. Add action `Set variable`
17. Set field `Variable Name` to `rawVar`
18. Add action `Text`
19. In the text field, add on under the other: `financialDataVar`, `currentPriceVar`, and `rawVar`
20. Add action `Show alert`
21. Instead of `Do you want to continue?` insert `Text`

Clicking on the play button shows a pop-up window, but, unfortunately, without any content.

My questions:

1. What steps do I have to do in order to get AAPL current stock price when I click on the play button?
2. Is there a way to ask the user to input their own ticker (say MSFT, or TSLA, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure 1**

Steps to get AAPL current stock price when clicking on the play button (one of the ways, at least):

1. Open the Shortcuts app
2. Click on the `+` sign to create a new shortcut
3. Add action `Get contents of URL`
4. Insert URL `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?query=AAPL*&type=equity`
5. Add action `Get dictionary from input` (which should automatically gets the dictionary from the URL)
6. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
7. Insert the following Key: `finance`
8. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
9. Insert the following Key: `result`
10. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
11. Insert the following Key: `documents`
12. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
13. Insert the following Key: `regularMarketPrice`
14. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
15. Insert the following Key: `raw`
16. Add action `Set Variable`
17. Insert a Variable Name, e.g.,: `rawShareVar`
18. Add action `Show Result`
19. Shortcut should automatically fill the Result with the last variable name (i.e., `rawShareVar`)
20. When you click for the first time on play (or Cmd-R), Shortcuts will ask something like: `Allow [name of the shortcut] to connect to "query1.finance.yahoo.com"?`, click on `Allow`
21. A pop-up window appears with the current price of the chosen stock (in this case AAPL)
22. Click on `Done` to close the pop-up.

Here below a screen grab of algorithm:
[image: Screenshot of the first algorithm.]

---

**Procedure 2**

Steps to get any stock price by prompting the user when clicking on the play button (one of the ways, at least):

1. Open the Shortcuts app
2. Click on the `+` sign to create a new shortcut
3. Add action `Ask for Input`
4. Check that the action asks for `Text`
5. Replace `Prompt` with `Enter a ticker symbol`
6. Add action `Set Variable`
7. In the `Variable Name` field type something like `tickerVar`
8. Erase `tickerVar` that was automatically inserted by the app
9. Insert URL `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?query=AAPL*&type=equity`
10. Within the URL erase AAPL
11. Start typing `tickerVar` and select it
12. It should look like this: `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/lookup?query=tickerVar*&type=equity`
13. Add action `Get dictionary from input` (which should automatically gets the dictionary from the URL)
14. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
15. Insert the following Key: `finance`
16. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
17. Insert the following Key: `result`
18. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
19. Insert the following Key: `documents`
20. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
21. Insert the following Key: `regularMarketPrice`
22. Add action `Get Dictionary Value`
23. Insert the following Key: `raw`
24. Add action `Set Variable`
25. Insert a Variable Name, e.g.,: `rawTickerVar`
26. Add action `Show Result`
27. The Shortcut app should automatically fill the Result with the last variable name (i.e., `rawTickerVar`)
28. When you click for the first time on play (or Cmd-R), Shortcuts will first ask to type the ticker name (e.g., MSFT)
29. Then it will ask something like: `Allow [name of the shortcut] to connect to "query1.finance.yahoo.com"?`, click on `Allow`
30. A pop-up window appears with the current price of the chosen stock (in this case AAPL)
31. Click on `Done` to close the pop-up.

Here below a screen grab of algorithm:
[image: Screenshot of the second algorithm.]